# idata.frame: Why error "is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE"?

Tags: performance, r, plyr, data.table

I'm working with a large data frame called exp ([file here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1krGGny7BduNjMxYjAyNDUtYjAwNy00MTM0LWJlZjUtZTAyZGQyMzFiOTY5&hl=en&authkey=CMvtpuMP)) in R.  In the interests of performance, it was suggested that I check out the idata.frame() function from plyr. But I think I'm using it wrong.

My original call, slow but it works:

```
df.median<-ddply(exp, 
                 .(groupname,starttime,fPhase,fCycle), 
                 numcolwise(median), 
                 na.rm=TRUE)
```

With idata.frame, `Error: is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE`

```
library(plyr)
df.median<-ddply(idata.frame(exp), 
                 .(groupname,starttime,fPhase,fCycle), 
                 numcolwise(median), 
                 na.rm=TRUE)
```

So, I thought, perhaps it is my data.  So I tried the `baseball` dataset. The `idata.frame` example works fine: `dlply(idata.frame(baseball), "id", nrow)` But if I try something similar to my desired call using `baseball`, it doesn't work:

```
bb.median<-ddply(idata.frame(baseball), 
                 .(id,year,team), 
                 numcolwise(median), 
                 na.rm=TRUE)
>Error: is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE
```

Perhaps my error is in how I'm specifying the groupings?  Anyone know how to make my example work?

ETA:

I also tried:

```
groupVars <- c("groupname","starttime","fPhase","fCycle")
voi<-c('inadist','smldist','lardist')

i<-idata.frame(exp)
ag.median <- aggregate(i[,voi], i[,groupVars], median)
Error in i[, voi] : object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

which uses a faster way of getting the medians, but gives a different error. I don't think I understand how to use idata.frame at all.

Comment: Yes, `idata.frame` is still experimental so it's better to work with it directly rather than using of the summary functions like `colwise`

Comment: Given you are looking for performance with big data, I would invest time in looking at the  `data.table` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are working with 'big' data  and looking for perfomance, this seems a perfect fit for `data.table`.

Specifically  the `lapply(.SD,FUN)`  and `.SDcols` arguments with `by`

Setup the `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(exp)
iexp <- idata.frame(exp)
```

Which columns are `numeric`

```
numeric_columns <- names(which(unlist(lapply(DT, is.numeric))))



dt.median <- DT[, lapply(.SD, median), by = list(groupname, starttime, fPhase, 
    fCycle), .SDcols = numeric_columns]
```

## some benchmarking

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(data.table = DT[, lapply(.SD, median), by = list(groupname, starttime, 
    fPhase, fCycle), .SDcols = numeric_columns], 
 plyr = ddply(exp, .(groupname, starttime, fPhase, fCycle), numcolwise(median), na.rm = TRUE), 
 idataframe = ddply(exp, .(groupname, starttime, fPhase, fCycle), function(x) data.frame(inadist = median(x$inadist), 
        smldist = median(x$smldist), lardist = median(x$lardist), inadur = median(x$inadur), 
        smldur = median(x$smldur), lardur = median(x$lardur), emptyct = median(x$emptyct), 
        entct = median(x$entct), inact = median(x$inact), smlct = median(x$smlct), 
        larct = median(x$larct), na.rm = TRUE)), 
 aggregate = aggregate(exp[, numeric_columns],
                       exp[, c("groupname", "starttime", "fPhase", "fCycle")], 
              median), 
 replications = 5)

##         test replications elapsed relative user.self 
## 4  aggregate            5    5.42    1.789      5.30   
## 1 data.table            5    3.03    1.000      3.03    
## 3 idataframe            5   11.81    3.898     11.77       
## 2       plyr            5    9.47    3.125      9.45
```

Comment: Nice! I may include this in the next refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behaviour, but even in the docs it says that idata.frame is experimental. You probably found a bug. Perhaps you could rewrite the check at the top of ddply that tests is.data.frame().

In any case, this cuts about 20% off the time (on my system):

```
system.time(df.median<-ddply(exp, .(groupname,starttime,fPhase,fCycle), function(x) data.frame(
inadist=median(x$inadist),
smldist=median(x$smldist),
lardist=median(x$lardist),
inadur=median(x$inadur),
smldur=median(x$smldur),
lardur=median(x$lardur),
emptyct=median(x$emptyct),
entct=median(x$entct),
inact=median(x$inact),
smlct=median(x$smlct),
larct=median(x$larct),
na.rm=TRUE))
)
```

Shane asked you in another post if you could cache the results of your script. I don't really have an idea of your workflow, but it may be best to setup a chron to run this and store the results, daily/hourly whatever.

Comment: that's interesting that specifying the columns speeds things up (it does so on my system too), but so far the fastest solution is to use `aggregate()`. In any event, the reason I used my old slow call in this question was because it caused `idata.frame()` to choke. I have a lot of calls that use the exp data frame, and I thought if I could substitute an idata.frame, it might speed up all the calls significantly.

Comment: You can use `idata.frame` with this call - but it only gives about a 10% speed up because you're not making that many splits.

Comment: And yes, `aggregate` will currently beat `ddply` + `colwise`.  Thinking about how to do better for the next version.